# How make viewpager to slide image with image's url?

Tags: android, image, url, android-viewpager, load

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tM7rwJoK-18) to make an image slider with images url but the slider is empty.

Here is my adapter's code:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapterUrl extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<String> photosUrl= new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapterUrl(Context context, ArrayList<String> photosUrl){

        this.context = context;
        this.photosUrl = photosUrl;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return photosUrl.size();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

         layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_layout, null);
         ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

         Picasso.get().load(photosUrl.get(position)).into(imageView);
         container.addView(imageView);
         return imageView;
     }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }
}
```

Here is the activity where i want to show the adapter:

```
public class UrlActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Advertisement adv;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_url);

    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    //adv is a custom object that contain an arraylist<String> of url. 
    adv = (Advertisement)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("adv");

    ViewPagerAdapterUrl viewPagerAdapterUrl = new ViewPagerAdapterUrl(this, adv.getPhotosUrl());
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapterUrl);
}
```

}

EDIT
I found this in debug but it isn't show like an error:

method int android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView

Comment: Check `photosUrl` does contains all valid URLs . Also make sure you have Internet permission in manifest ..

Comment: Internet permission is set and the urls are valid(i take then from my firebase Storage folder)

Comment: Replace `return imageView;` with `return view;`. Also post your whole adapter's code.

Comment: As soon as i can i’ll post the code, now i’m on the bus. Thank for your help.

Comment: i updated my question with all the code and a possible error

Comment: Your code looks OK to me ..Just try after setting an image from drawable a sample image . Just to make sure that Your layout and Adapter are working fine .

Comment: It working fine with drowable images

Comment: Okay then problem with `Picasso.get().load(photosUrl.get(position)).into(imageView);` . I have not used `Picasso` since a while .. I usually use `Glide`.You can give it a try . Also can you add an image Url with question which you are using .

Comment: I tried a simple adapter with Uri and it worked. If i change the adapter for showing images url both picasso and glide it doesn’t work( i already tried)

Comment: Can you send some image URLs you are using .

Comment: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/firestore-faeec.appspot.com/o/image.jpg?alt=media&token=63b8107c-1443-4a49-814f-52a935eaa2f3 this is an immage in my firestore Storage

Comment: Tested . Working file at my end .. Are you sure you are passing the right URL to Picasso . Also double check Internet Permission in manifest .. Debug the code and check the URL ..

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> i use this permission. I tried tho show in a text view all the links of my arraylist, they're equal to the links showed in firebase storage

Comment: i don't specify the extension of the file...is this the problem? or the size of the images?